# How do I make my navigation dropdown activate on hover in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking for a way to activate my navigation menu on hover on desktop.

I've found snippets for Bootstrap v3, but I've found none of those codes translate to v4.

Here is my nav HTML & CSS for http://beaudeelashbar.com:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark fixed-top scrolling-navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseEx2" aria-controls="collapseEx2" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
        </a>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapseEx2">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="http://beaudeelashbar.com/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="http://beaudeelashbar.com/about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="http://beaudeelashbar.com/packages">Packages & Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="http://beaudeelashbar.com/faq">FAQ</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="http://beaudeelashbar.com/#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

.navbar:hover .nabvar-collapse {
display: block;
}

.navbar .navbar-collapse {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
width: 200px;
float: right;
margin-top: 47px;
margin-right: -17px;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link {
color: #fff;
}

.nav-item {
padding-right: 15px;
}

.nav-link {
float: right;
}

.scrolling-navbar {
    -webkit-transition: background .5s ease-in-out, padding .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background .5s ease-in-out, padding .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: background .5s ease-in-out, padding .5s ease-in-out;
    height: 55px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    box-shadow: none;
}

.top-nav-collapse {
background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: look for the jquery that targets `<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right">` and change the click function to hover and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
button.navbar-toggler:hover ~ .navbar-collapse {
    display: block;
}
```

better to try with **`<ul>`** and **`<li>`** for dropdown because dropdown appears only when we hover the button element.That is not what we need. so it's better to create a dropdown using **`<ul>`** and **`<li>`** elements.

Hope this works..